# Relation between Radiance and Surface power density (i.e poynting vector intensity)

Tags: electromagnetism, power, microwaves, poynting-vector, radiometry

I am attending a microwave remote sensing course and I have same problem to understand the relation between the radiance and the intensity of poynting's vector.

The radiance is defined as:

$L(\theta,\varphi)=\frac{d\Phi^2}{d\Omega\,dA_{\perp}}=\frac{d\Phi^2}{d\Omega\,dA\, cos\theta}$

where $dA_{\perp}=dA\, cos\theta$ is the surface orthogonal to the direction $(\theta,\varphi)$ in which the radiance $L$ is observed.

the intensity of the Poynting's Vector $P$ is defined as:

$P(\theta,\varphi)=\frac{d\Phi}{dA_{\perp}}=\frac{d\Phi}{dA\,cos\theta}$

since that, we should have that:

$L(\theta,\varphi)=\frac{d\Phi^2}{d\Omega\,dA_{\perp}}=\frac{d}{d\Omega}\Big(\frac{d\Phi}{dA\,cos\theta}\Big)=\frac{dP}{d\Omega}$

so:

$dP(\theta,\varphi)=L(\theta,\varphi)d\Omega$

right?

the problem is that the intensity of the poynting's vector should depends on the observation direction defined by the angle $(\theta,\varphi)$, but using the previous formula we have that:

$P=\int L(\theta,\varphi)d\Omega$

and since we integrate on the solid angle $d\Omega$, the dependence on the angular variables $\theta,\varphi$ is exhausted. So where is the error in my consideration?

Comment: But when expressing $d \Omega$ in spherical coordinates you get theta and phi back, don't you...? (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle)

Comment: P should be a function of $\theta,\varphi$ but if we integrate $L(\theta,\varphi)$ on the solid angle $\Omega_o$ respect ti $d\Omega$, P doesn't depend anymore from $\theta,\varphi$... Right?

Comment: As far as I know, the time average of the Poynting vector is the irradiance in $W/m^2$. The radiance is the same but per solid angle. Integrating the radiance over the solid angle gives therefore the irradiance... so should be consistent.